# How to report number of function evaluations in a C++ program

Tags: c++

I had written a C++ program which calculates the objective function value for an algorithm which minimizes a function. I would like to know how many objective function evaluations did the algorithm use. there are also many other functions which call the call the objective value function.

I have a demo code here...

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <stdlib.h>    


using namespace std;

void prnt(){
    static int num = 0;
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    num++;
    cout << num << endl;
}

void callprnt(){
    prnt();
}

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        prnt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        callprnt();
    }

}
```

As you can see, i can display in `prnt()` the function how many objective function evaluation are occurring but I would like to access this in main. Any idea how to efficiently track the number of function evaluations in the main?

Comment: `int prnt(){ static int num = 0;  return num; }`

Comment: You need to declare `static int num = 0;` outside any function so that it's visible also from the `main` function, otherwise it's scope/visibility is limited to the function where you defined it, even though it's a static variable. Static here only influences the lifetime of the variable, not its scope/visibility.

Comment: @DeiDei  the actual prnt() function is a returns a double value

Comment: @nbro should I then pass num as a pointer to the prnt() function?

Comment: @Morpheus No, you don't have to, it will be visible and accessible from all functions defined in that file.

Comment: @nbro  Seems to work but are there any downsides?

Comment: @Morpheus Given your simple code, I don't think there are any downsides, but global variables in bigger programs can cause some conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this.

A bad way is to use a global variable.

Better ways are to return the number of counts, or to pass in  a variable (as as a pointer or reference) to keep track.

Alternatively you could keep track in a class.

```
using namespace std;

class Printer
{
public:
    Printer() : num(0) {}
    void prnt() {
        cout << "Hello" << endl;
        num++;
        cout << num << endl;
    }
    int count()
    {
        return num;
    }
private:
    int num;
};

void callprnt(Printer & p) {
    p.prnt();
}

int main() {
    Printer p;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        p.prnt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        callprnt(p);
    }

    cout << "Total count: " << p.count() << '\n';
}
```

In general you could make the `Printer` actually a counter, and pass in the function you need to call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. it seems a bit complicated for me but I will try to understand it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++17, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<auto> struct counter { static int value; };
template<auto F> int counter<F>::value = 0;

void prnt() { ++counter<&prnt>::value; }
void callprnt() { ++counter<&callprnt>::value; prnt(); }

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { prnt(); }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { callprnt(); }
    std::cout << counter<&prnt>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << counter<&callprnt>::value << std::endl;
}
```

In C++14 you can use the following definitions:

```
template<void(*)()> struct counter { static int value; };
template<void(*F)()> int counter<F>::value = 0;
```

Anyway, they are constrained to function type `void(void)`.
With a bit of work you can probably adapt the solution so that it accepts any kind of function type.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename R, typename... A>
struct family {
    template<R(*)(A...)>
    struct wrapper {
        static int value;
    };
};

template<typename R, typename... A>
template<R(*F)(A...)>
int family<R, A...>::wrapper<F>::value = 0;

template<typename R, typename... A>
constexpr family<R, A...> fam(R(*)(A...));

void prnt() { ++decltype(fam(&prnt))::template wrapper<prnt>::value; }
void callprnt() { ++decltype(fam(&callprnt))::template wrapper<callprnt>::value; prnt(); }

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) { prnt(); }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { callprnt(); }
    std::cout << decltype(fam(&prnt))::template wrapper<prnt>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << decltype(fam(&callprnt))::template wrapper<callprnt>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@nbro helped me with this:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <stdlib.h>    


using namespace std;

static int num = 0;


void prnt(){

    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    num++;
}

void callprnt(){
    prnt();
}

int main() {


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        prnt();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        callprnt();
    }

    cout << "The total number of iterations is " << num << endl;

}
```

I am a bit unsure if this is the best way or if it can be done a bit better.

Looks like there are better ways to do it..